# calculate Fourier Transformate

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, fourier-transform

i have the following exercice:

Let for all $x \in \mathbb{R},$ $f(x)= \cos x$ and $g(x)= \sin x$.

1. Calculate $T=f \delta' + g \delta''$
   for this question, i find $T=3 \delta$.
2. Calculate the Fourier transormates $F(f \delta')$ and $F(g \delta'')$.

How i can caculate the transformates Fourier in this question 2?. Please.

$\delta$ is Dirac distribution, and we define the Fourier transformate of an function $g$, as 
$$F(g)(\xi)= \displaystyle\int g(x) e^{-i x \xi} dx$$

Comment: How are $\delta,\delta'$, and $\delta''$ defined?  Do you mean Dirac Delta?

Also, how are you normalizing your fourier transform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distributional derivative of the Dirac delta distribution is the distribution $\delta′$ defined on compactly supported smooth test functions $\varphi$ by
$$
    \delta'[\varphi] = -\delta[\varphi']=-\varphi'(0).
$$
The first equality here is a kind of integration by parts, for if $\delta$ were a true function then
$$
    \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(x)\varphi(x)\,dx = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)\varphi'(x)\,dx.
$$
The $k$-th derivative of $\delta$ is defined similarly as the distribution given on test functions by
$$
    \delta^{(k)}[\varphi] = (-1)^k \varphi^{(k)}(0). 
$$

If $f$ is $n$ times differentiable around $x_0\in\Bbb R$ we have
$$
f(x)\delta^{(n)}(x-x_0)=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}f^{(n-k)}(x_0)\delta^{(k)}(x-x_0)
$$
So you have for $n=1$ and $n=2$ and $x_0=0$
\begin{align}
T &=f(x) \delta'(x)+g(x)  \delta''(x)\\
&=- \delta(x) f'(0)+ \delta(x) g''(0)+f(0)  \delta'(x)-2 g'(0)  \delta'(x)+g(0)  \delta''(x)\\
&=\delta'(x)-2 \delta'(x)\\&=-\delta'(x)
\end{align}
using $f(0)=1,\,f'(0)=0, g(0)=0,\,g'(0)=1,\,g''(0)=0$.

For the Fourier transform use $$\mathcal F\{\delta(x)\}=\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x) e^{- ix\xi}\,dx=1$$
and $$
\mathcal F\{f^{(n)}(x)\}(\xi)=  (i\xi)^n \mathcal F\{f(x)\}(\xi)
$$
that  is $$\mathcal F\{\delta^{(n)}(x)\}=  (i\xi)^n \cdot 1 $$
So we have
\begin{align}
\mathcal F\left\{f(x) \delta'(x)\right\}&=\mathcal F\left\{- \delta(x) f'(0)+f(0)  \delta'(x)\right\}\\
&=- f'(0)+f(0) i\xi\\
&= i\xi
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\mathcal F\left\{g(x)  \delta''(x)\right\}&=\mathcal F\left\{\delta(x) g''(0)-2 g'(0)  \delta'(x)+g(0)  \delta''(x)\right\}\\
&=g''(0)-2 g'(0)  i\xi+g(0)  (i\xi)^2\\
&=-2  i\xi
\end{align}
and then

$$
\mathcal F\left\{T(x)\right\}=\mathcal F\left\{f(x) \delta'(x)\right\}+\mathcal F\left\{g(x)  \delta''(x)\right\}=\mathcal F\left\{- \delta'(x)\right\}=- i \xi
$$

Comment: this is for question 1, and for question 2? Please.

Comment: Thak you so much for this answer. Please, just one question: why ws have $F(\delta)= 2 \pi?$ and why $F(\delta^{(n)})= (i \xi)^n 2 \pi$? and why $$F(f \delta')= F(-\delta f'(0)+f(0) \delta')?$$ Please

Comment: $\mathcal F\{\delta\}=1$, there was a typo... From the property of differentiation we have $\mathcal F\{f^{(n)}\}=(i\xi)^n \mathcal F\{f\}$ and then for $f=\delta$ we have $\mathcal F\{\delta^{(n)}\}=(i\xi)^n \mathcal F\{\delta\}=(i\xi)^n\cdot 1$.

Comment: We have $f(x)\delta'(x)=- \delta(x) f'(0)+f(0)  \delta'(x)$ where $f'(0)=0, \,f(0)=1$ are constants. So by the linearity of Fourier transform $\mathcal F\left\{f(x) \delta'(x)\right\}=\mathcal F\left\{- \delta(x) f'(0)+f(0)  \delta'(x)\right\}=-f'(0)\mathcal F\left\{\delta(x)\right\} +f(0)  \mathcal F\left\{\delta'(x)\right\}=-0\cdot 1+1\cdot \mathcal F\left\{\delta'(x)\right\}=i\xi$.